# usb3 device only detected as usb2 device

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I've got a bug filed as my USB3 thumb drive in Maverick and Natty only gets detected as a USB2 device (please find some details below).

[Launchpad bug record](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/710153)

- Has anyone an idea how to troubleshoot that further or get it fixed?
- Can anybody confirm USB3 devices working on an ASUS M4A88TD-V EVO/USB3 motherboard (with a NEC uPD720200 USB 3.0 onboard chip) on any of both USB3 ports?

#### What I've also done to troubleshoot/fix without success is:

- checked all USB ports to be sure not to use the wrong one
- blacklisted the usb2 kernel module (ehci_hcd) to enforce loading of usb3 kernel module (xhci_hcd) while connecting the thumb drive
- checked different upstream kernel instead of the default Ubuntu kernel
- checked different Ubuntu kernel (also from kernal-ppa)

Comment: Are you sure, you plugged it into an USB3-Port on your computer? Some (cheaper) pcs have both usb2 and usb3 ports.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Flash Drive